# Will my new adhesive-backed cork tiles adhere to my existing sheet vinyl?

Tags: bathroom, tile, vinyl, cork

I have a vinyl floor, not tiles one full piece, over concrete, in my bathroom.
The vinyl is solid and perfectly fitting to all the walls and runs beneath the bath, shower, toilet, sink and fitted wall cupboards. It is screwed to.  The vinyl floor was there in an empty room before the bathroom was created. The only way it could be completely removed would be to remove the complete bathroom, this is not an option :-).

I am looking to tile over the vinyl with cork tiles. 
**The questions is: will normal cork tile adhesive stick ok to the vinyl or should I treat the vinyl in some way?**

Comment: @mike  Are you sure tiles are adhesive backed?  I read the last sentence to imply a spreadable mastic.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the responses. They are not self adhesive so I will need a glue and it is vinyl. Thanks for the responses I feel the answer from Jacob S meets my needs, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer for certain, but adhesive is still adhesive (no different than laying vinyl on top of vinyl), so I would *assume* (possibly incorrectly) that the adhesive is similar.

I can only say what I would do if this were something I was going to try -- my thought would be to clean first with a good degreaser, then with vinegar and water so that I had an extremely clean surface.

I would only consider this if the old vinyl is smooth on the surface. If not, I would approach it just like when laying vinyl over vinyl, following the recommendations from [Lowes](http://www.lowes.com/cd_Install+Sheet+Vinyl+Flooring_799540029_) to use a coat of embossing leveler with a straight-edged trowel.

Once completely cleaned and with a smooth surface, I would lay the cork.